# Getting integer values from string and double it

Tags: java

I get a string that consists of a number and then some text, eg; "23 test", "600 tests test" the string will always start with the number but it has no set length.
How do i get the number value and double it?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please show some effort.

Comment: Double.valueOf(s.split("\s")[0])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String example = "600 test";
return Double.parseDouble ( example.substring ( 0, example.indexOf(" ")));
```

Answer (score 0):

split on space, take the value on 0th index, convert it into Integer and double the value

```
String s = "23 test";
Integer.parseInt(s.split(" ")[0]) * 2
```

Please make sure that all strings follow the same format else there will be a numberFormatException

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following.

//Assumption that there is always a space after the number.
Lets say String string = "23 test";

String stringArray = string.split("");

String number = stringArray[0];

System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(number)*2);